# include user photoUrl from firebase google auth, when comment or post an article

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Does anyone know how to include user photoUrl from firebase Google auth when post an article? NB: I use glide for displaying my google photourl

Answer (score 0):

Google auth provider supplies the user's displayName, email and photoUrl. Anytime after you've authenticated with Google you can do this:

```
ImageView photoImageView;    

FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
    Glide.with(this).load(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(photoImageView);
}
```